# DataTables custom dropdown date filter

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

Here's the link to my test file
http://www.ollitrop.com/index.html

I'm creating a new dropdown with the label 'Sort By Year' that pulls all the dates from 'Date' in the JSON file. Ideally, the Sort By Year dropdown would only show the years so in this case, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, and 2012. The user could select '2008' and it would show only listings in 2008.

Thank you in advance!

**JSON file**
http://www.ollitrop.com/sample.json

**JS File:**
http://ollitrop.com/notice-grid.js

Current JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'sample.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: jsonParser
    });
    // hide grid on load
    $('#gridNotices').hide();
});

function jsonParser(json){
    $('#load').fadeOut();
    $.getJSON('sample.json',function(data){

        // Build Notices Grid
        var noticesGridDataTemplate = $('#gridNoticeTemplate').html(),
            noticesGridHTML = Mustache.to_html(noticesGridDataTemplate, data);
        $('#notice').html(noticesGridHTML);
        $('#gridNotices').DataTable({
            //"bPaginate": false,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "paging": false,
            initComplete: function () {
                this.api().columns(0).every(function () {

                    var column = this;

                    var selectDropdown = $('<select><option></option></select>')
                        .appendTo($('#sort-by-year'))
                        .on('change', function () {
                            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                $(this).val()

                            );
                            column
                                .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                                .draw();
                        });

                    column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
                        selectDropdown.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
                    });
                });
            }
        });

        $('#gridNotices').show();

    });
}
```

Comment: as per i understand your question you  want to diaplay on Year in dropdown ?

Comment: @CY5 Yes. I want to get all the years associated with the Dates in the JSOn without any duplicates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Convert the string to date, get the year, then use that in the select. You can store the years in an array as you go to make sure there are no duplicates.

```
// -- snip -- //
initComplete: function () {
    this.api().columns(0).every(function () {

        var column = this;

        var selectDropdown = $('<select><option></option></select>')
                .appendTo($('#sort-by-year'))
                .on('change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );
                    column
                        .search(val ? val + '$' : '', true, false)
                        .draw();
                });

        var dates = [];

        column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
            var date = new Date(d), year = date.getFullYear();
            if (dates.indexOf(year) < 0) {
                dates.push(year);
                selectDropdown.append('<option value="' + year + '">' + year + '</option>');
            }
        });
    });
}
// -- snip -- //
```

Comment: This may not be the best or most efficient approach, but it should work. I'll check back later when I have some more time to spend on it to see if I can refine it.

Comment: You're welcome @Hectooorr -- if you found my answer helpful, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Hi @mason81 I think you solved it half way. I am able to get the dropdown with the years as options but I can't filter the table to have it show all entries based on that year.

Comment: @Hectooorr ok i updated, i removed `'^' + ` from the `column.search(...)` since that was telling it to look for dates matching exactly the year, now it will match them ending with the year.

Comment: life saver! Thank you for helping me out.